# Column comparison & column copying

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames, **df1** and **df2**:

```
 >>> import pandas as pd
 >>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'pkid': [1, 2], 'files': ['f1', 'f2']})
 >>> df1
       files  pkid
     0    f1     1
     1    f2     2
 >>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'records': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'files': ['f1', 'f1', 'f2', 'f1', 'f2', 'f2']})
 >>> df2
       files  records
     0    f1        1
     1    f1        2
     2    f2        3
     3    f1        4
     4    f2        5
     5    f2        6
```

I am looking to create a third column in **df2** called **files_fkid**.

I would like a solution where the files column from **df1** is compared with the files column in **df2**, and **df1**'s respective **pkid** is placed in the new **files_fkid** column of **df2**.  so the new **df2** will print as:

```
>>> df2
       files  records  files_fkid
     0    f1        1           1
     1    f1        2           1
     2    f2        3           2
     3    f1        4           1
     4    f2        5           2
     5    f2        6           2
```

Can anyone think of a concise pandas solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A faster method than @ajcr's is to use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map) here because you have a unique index then this will be much faster than calling apply which is essentially a for loop:

```
In [15]:

df1_ = df1.set_index('files')
%timeit df2['files_fkid'] = df2['files'].map(df1_['pkid'])
df2
1000 loops, best of 3: 636 µs per loop
Out[15]:
  files  records  files_fkid
0    f1        1           1
1    f1        2           1
2    f2        3           2
3    f1        4           1
4    f2        5           2
5    f2        6           2
In [17]:

df1_ = df1.set_index('files')
%timeit df2['files_fkid'] = df2.files.apply(lambda x: df1_.loc[x])
df2
100 loops, best of 3: 2.61 ms per loop
Out[17]:
  files  records  files_fkid
0    f1        1           1
1    f1        2           1
2    f2        3           2
3    f1        4           1
4    f2        5           2
5    f2        6           2
```

So you see that this is already 4 times faster and will scale much better. If you pass a series or dict as a form of lookup to map as a param, if the index is unique (which in this case it is and keys have to be unique for a dict) then the lookup will be blisteringly fast.

Comment: yep, this is MUCH better than using apply as its fully vectorized

Comment: Ah - I must remember to use `map` more often!

Comment: thank you for the solution!  does there happen to be a way to set and map according to multiple indices?

Comment: what do you mean? You mean for multiindex? not sure, my instinct would say no but I guess actually that would still work so long as the index was still unique

Comment: i want to make sure that many values in many columns match in order for the fkid to be copied.

Comment: Yes that will happen, map performs a lookup, so long as the column value exists in either the index of a series or key in a map as the param then it will set the value for all instances of that value

Answer (score 2):

You could use [pd.merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'pkid': [1, 2], 'files': ['f1', 'f2']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'records': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
                         , 'files': ['f1', 'f1', 'f2', 'f1', 'f2', 'f2']})

result = pd.merge(
    df2
    , df1.rename(columns={'pkid' : 'files_fkid'})
    , on=['files'], how='outer').sort(['records'])
```

yields

```
  files  records  files_fkid
0    f1        1           1
1    f1        2           1
3    f2        3           2
2    f1        4           1
4    f2        5           2
5    f2        6           2
```

Comment: i actually meant to compare multiple columns, but failed to include that in my example.  so, this solution works best in that case since i can just add to the on parameter of merge.  thanks!

Comment: i could not get the rename method to work without the keyword columns, like: df1.rename(columns={'pkid' : 'files_fkid'})

Answer (score 1):

You could set `files` as the index in `df1` and then apply a function which uses `loc` to look up the `pkid` value corresponding to the index:

```
>>> df1_ = df1.set_index('files')
>>> df2['files_fkid'] = df2.files.apply(lambda x: df1_.loc[x])
>>> df2
  files  records  files_fkid
0    f1        1           1
1    f1        2           1
2    f2        3           2
3    f1        4           1
4    f2        5           2
5    f2        6           2
```